# Default path for SQLite Store - Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite

```
app.use(session({
  store: new SQLiteStore,
  secret:"xxxxxx",
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
  rolling: true,
  resave: true
}));
```

By default new file with sessions named "sessions" is being created in a root directory. How to change default path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var session = require('express-session');
var SQLiteStore = require('connect-sqlite3')(session);
app.use(session({
    store: new SQLiteStore({dir:'./db/', db: 'sessions'}),
    ...
```