# Why is my require statement an immediately invoked function and why does it give errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, require

For uni I'm working on node.js servers. I'm following the code used in the lectures and I got in trouble with persistent sessions in express.js. In the lecture slides the following `require` is used:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var SQLiteStore = require('sqlite3')(session);
```

But when I used this in my code I get the following Error:

```
var SQLiteStore = require("sqlite3")(session);
                                    ^

TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jordv\OneDrive\Documenten\UU\2022 -2023\Blok 3\Web Technology\test\server.js:12:37)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I tried to find a solution for this online, and found this post [NodeJs : TypeError: require(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007878/nodejs-typeerror-require-is-not-a-function). I tried to understand the top answer but I just can't. I have two questions:

1. In the linked post, immediately invoked functions are mentioned. Why is my code an immediately invoked function? (My thought is that the error message states that it is not a function, so how is it immediately invoked?)
2. How is the answer to that post supposed to be applied to my situation?

**EDIT:**
In the comments it was suggested to `console.log(sqlite3)`. this gives

```
{
  Database: [Function: Database],
  Statement: [Function: Statement],
  Backup: [Function: Backup],
  OPEN_READONLY: 1,
  OPEN_READWRITE: 2,
  OPEN_CREATE: 4,
  OPEN_FULLMUTEX: 65536,
  OPEN_URI: 64,
  OPEN_SHAREDCACHE: 131072,
  OPEN_PRIVATECACHE: 262144,
  VERSION: '3.41.1',
  SOURCE_ID: '2023-03-10 12:13:52 20399f3eda5ec249d147ba9e48da6e87f969d7966a9a896764ca437ff7e737ff',
  VERSION_NUMBER: 3041001,
  OK: 0,
  ERROR: 1,
  INTERNAL: 2,
  PERM: 3,
  ABORT: 4,
  BUSY: 5,
  LOCKED: 6,
  NOMEM: 7,
  READONLY: 8,
  INTERRUPT: 9,
  IOERR: 10,
  CORRUPT: 11,
  NOTFOUND: 12,
  FULL: 13,
  CANTOPEN: 14,
  PROTOCOL: 15,
  EMPTY: 16,
  SCHEMA: 17,
  TOOBIG: 18,
  CONSTRAINT: 19,
  MISMATCH: 20,
  MISUSE: 21,
  NOLFS: 22,
  AUTH: 23,
  FORMAT: 24,
  RANGE: 25,
  NOTADB: 26,
  LIMIT_LENGTH: 0,
  LIMIT_SQL_LENGTH: 1,
  LIMIT_COLUMN: 2,
  LIMIT_EXPR_DEPTH: 3,
  LIMIT_COMPOUND_SELECT: 4,
  LIMIT_VDBE_OP: 5,
  LIMIT_FUNCTION_ARG: 6,
  LIMIT_ATTACHED: 7,
  LIMIT_LIKE_PATTERN_LENGTH: 8,
  LIMIT_VARIABLE_NUMBER: 9,
  LIMIT_TRIGGER_DEPTH: 10,
  LIMIT_WORKER_THREADS: 11,
  cached: { Database: [Function: Database], objects: {} },
  verbose: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Comment: Clearly `require('sqlite3')(session);` and `sqlite3(session);` are different. Why do you expect `sqlite3` to be defined?

Comment: You have to declare the variable first `const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3')`

Comment: apologies, was trying some things in the hope that that would solve the problem. I've edited the post

Comment: can you post more context? for example the lesson part regarding the session.
i am assuming the package being used is this one, is that correct? https://github.com/theogravity/express-session-sqlite

Comment: Try doing `const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3"); console.log(sqlite3);` to see what it's returning.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3 makes no mention of the package exporting a function.

Comment: @Sombriks we use ```express-session``` and ```sqlite3```

Comment: @JordvanEldik are you absolutely sure the exercise says `sqlite3` and shows `var SQLiteStore = require('sqlite3')(session);`? And not about `connect-sqlite3`? Like shown here [Default path for SQLite Store - Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383334)

Comment: @t.niese yes I'm sure. But i can divert from the course material if i want. Would replacing `sqlite3` with `connect-sqlite3` not mess with other things? It does indeed resolve the error.

Comment: @JordvanEldik If it really talks about `sqlite3` and shows `var SQLiteStore = require('sqlite3')(session);` then you should talk with the one who supervises the course, and ask that person which module should be used. We don't know which module should be used and if using a different one would result in later problems.

Comment: @t.niese I'll message the supervisor. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If only basic session functionality is used, then I guess it will work because it is just an adapter for the session storage. But it is better to ask about that.